# I'm unable to see a deleted post. How can I see and undelete it?

Tags: support, deleted-posts

I deleted a post today on Hinduism SE and am not able to see the deleted post for undeleting or editing it. Reputation is not yet adequate.

Comment: @Rathony: That's a different situation and only the third answer addresses this at all.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Well, the third answer actually answers this question and the previous question. The problem is the accepted answer is not the answer to the question.

Comment: @Rathony But we VTC based on questions, not answers. That question is looking for **all** posts that have been deleted, this one is looking for a specific one.

Comment: @Catija If you don't agree to close it, you can just move on.

Comment: @Rathony Explaining why a dupe close is wrong is helpful to reviewers. Your attitude is unnecessary.

Comment: @Catija Nathan Tuggy already mentioned it. At least two users seem to agree with me. Let's move on.

Comment: @Catija Why did you close-vote it when you didn't seem to agree with the close reason? What's the point of your comment?

Comment: @Rathony I VTC for a different reason. I did not VTC as a dupe.

Comment: @Catija I would not close this question if I didn't find it already answered. Any other reason? I am curious.

Comment: @Rathony It should have been asked on Hinduism's Meta.

Comment: @Catija I disagree. This question is related with one of the across-SE features and the OP doesn't need to ask there. Actually this kind of question is better asked here because there are more experts here on across-SE features and how they've been changed and implemented.

Comment: @Rathony But if asked there, the mods or high rep users could have linked them to the post directly... particularly in the case of a very old post.

Comment: @Catija Mods and high-rep users are not there to do some errands for those who don't know how to find their deleted posts. If you really thought that was the real reason to close this question, I don't agree. The OP must have learned how to find it already from the below answer or dupe master. What's the point of asking the OP to ask this question on Hinduism SE's Meta?

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to [your profile](//hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/current).
2. Go to either your [answers tab](//hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=answers) or [questions tab](//hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=questions), depending if the deleted post is answer or question.
3. You will see in the bottom "deleted recent answers" or "deleted recent questions" link. Click it, and you'll see the post you deleted.

This will show deleted posts that have been **posted** in the past 60 days, meaning if a post was posted more than 60 days ago and deleted just now, it will not appear in those lists.

If you deleted a post older than 60 days but have the [access to moderator tools](//hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege (10k on graduated sites, 2k on beta sites) you can see all your deleted posts by searching for `deleted:1` e.g. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=deleted%3A1 and note that users without this privilege will just see the search results for "deleted:1" as a string.

If you deleted a post older than 60 days and don't have the access to moderator tools privilege, try looking in your browser history. Otherwise, the only way is asking a site moderator to have a look, since they can see deleted posts in users profile.

Comment: I don't think the 60-day restriction applies to diamond moderators, so if all else fails, ask your site moderator to retrieve the post for you.

Comment: @Dave correct, diamond moderator can see all deleted posts in user's profile, regardless of their age, but bothering a moderator for such a thing should be the last resort.

Comment: That's what "if all else fails" means...

Comment: @Dave lol, very true! :)